# Importing MySQLdb (mysqlclient module) from Python throws an openssl-related error in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: python, openssl, homebrew

There are similar questions in StackOverflow, but none of them fully worked for me in Mac OS Catalina, February, 2020. I didn't even try the ones involving massive changes of permissions, links or low-level workarounds that one will probably pay in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with a similar but safer solution:

```
brew uninstall openssl
```

Homebrew will probably warn you about other packages that depend on it, specially `mysql`, and maybe `python@3.8` or others. **Don't force it**, just uninstall all of them:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew uninstall python@3.8
brew uninstall ...  # everything you have as dependencies
brew uninstall openssl
```

Now just reinstall `mysql` and `openssl` will be reinstalled too automatically, this time without errors:

```
brew install mysql
```

Now everything will work again:

```
python
import MySQLdb
```

**Edit**

In case it is still failing, take a look if it is the cache of `pip` the one keeping the problem:

```
brew info openssl  # to copy your LDFLAGS path of the lib
pip uninstall mysqlclient
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib" pip install --no-cache-dir mysqlclient
python
import MySQLdb
```